# API Management retry policy

Tags: azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I have configured an API Management policy to retry in the case of 500 errors

```
<retry condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 500)" count="10" interval="10" max-interval="100" delta="10" first-fast-retry="false">
    <forward-request buffer-request-body="true" />
</retry>
```

I can see via app insights that it only ever appears to retry a maximum of four times.  Sometimes it tries once and sometimes twice

I would expect to see 10 attempts?

Comment: Does your backend consistently returns 500?

Comment: Not all the time no, there are successful calls in there as well

Comment: Retry will make a request and then evaluate condition, if it's true - request will be executed again. If response is still 500 another attempt will be made. Up untill retry count is reached or non 500 response is received. Does this fit your scenario?

Comment: That's what I have tried to code for in the policy but I can see it get four 500 results in a row and then nothing after that

Comment: Could you try to make a repro with test console in Azure portal and check traces there?